# How to run a .NET class library as a webservice

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2013, class-library

I have a web service built by colleagues as a class library that communicates with SharePoint 2013 on-premise. I now have to continue building this web service but there is no documentation on how to run and debug the class library. I have never done that my self. My question is how do I run a class library as a web service. How do communicate with the service thru requests and responses? I am used to communicating with services thru a `Controller` that got `ActionResults`. I know that this is an entirely different type of solution, but just so you know what I am used to working with.

Tell me if you want to see anything else. Any hints or solutions where to start learning how to run the web service is much appreciated

Some samples of the web service code:

> SharePointClient

```
internal string TestSharePoint()
{
Log.Debug("Hej från TestSharePoint");
var web = _clientContext.Web;
_clientContext.Load(web.AssociatedMemberGroup);
 _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
return web.AssociatedMemberGroup.Title;

}
```

> AccessLayer

```
  public string TestSharePoint(string siteUrl)
    {
        return _sharePointClient.TestSharePoint();
    }
```

> SPCRMIntegration

```
   public string TestSharePoint(string siteUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var accessLayer = IntegrationHelper.CreateAccessLayer(siteUrl))
            {
                return accessLayer.TestSharePoint(siteUrl);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

> ISPCRMIntegration

```
[OperationContract]
string TestSharePoint(string value);
```

Update:

This prompt says it all. Will add asp.net project and reference the class library.

[image]

Comment: I think you have a class library which does the actual job, and your web service is just exposing that functionality. Do you see two different projects for the class library and Webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You could not run a .NET class library.
Try creating a new ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET project and add a reference to that library. 
Register those methods in your own controller.

But I guess your problem was not running a 'class library' but running an ASP.NET web application. For after compiling an ASP.NET app it outputs a DLL file that looks like a class library.

Just deploy that file under IIS with ASP.NET module will start running it.

Comment: Added a pic in the question that say it all. you were right. But just to get my head around this. The actual web service is the asp.net project that got the class library reference in it?. Like an API.

Comment: Correct @AllramEst

Comment: Ok. stupid me, The I new all along what to do. Worked with APIs before but never class library. You learn something new everyday. It turns out after more digging in the project that it got an `.svc` file in it with endpoints. But now I am stuck on another problem with IIS denying me permission to show the file in the browser. Oh well, thats another stackowerflow question. Thanx for the help.